# Include a file which has included file in php [(!)Warning]

Tags: php, path, include

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: Why such weird behaviour when I include a file from another directory which also includes a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099357/php-why-such-weird-behaviour-when-i-include-a-file-from-another-directory-which)

I have a problem including a file that has an included file.

- core.inc.php PATH: `www/test/includes/core.inc.php`
- included file in core.inc.php  :  `include_once ('../../connectdb.php');`
- connectdb.php PATH: `www/connectdb.php`
- index.php PATH: `www/test/index.php`
- included file in index.php   : `include_once ('included/core.inc.php');`

When I run index.php the following warnings are popping up:

`(!) Warning: include_once(../../connectdb.php): failed to open stream: 
No such file or directory in G:\wamp\www\test\includes\core.inc.php on line 7`

`(!) Warning: include_once(): Failed opening '../../connectdb.php' for 
inclusion (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in G:\wamp\www\test\includes\core.inc.php on line 7`

In order to dinamically change the included paths what is the best practice? Please help me on my problem. Thank you.

Comment: Start relative paths with the directory of the current file, i.e. `require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/relative/path/to.file.php';`

Comment: Give path relative to your file you are editing..

Comment: This is a well-defined problem, with the quick-tip to use `__FILE__` and/or `__DIR__` to get the path of your file, not of your `include_path`. There are a lot of questions, for instance, the answer on this seems quite good, though the question itself is a bit long-ish. Just read the accepted answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099357/php-why-such-weird-behaviour-when-i-include-a-file-from-another-directory-which?rq=1

Comment: I have the following result: `Warning: require_once(G:\wamp\www\testincludes/core.inc.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in G:\wamp\www\test\index.php on line 13 `Back slash and forward slashes ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To avoid such problems, you may use PHP magic constant `__DIR__` which will be replaced by current file's directory.

For example:

```
include_once(__DIR__ . '/relative/path/to/file-to-include.php');
```

Note that `__DIR__` is only available for PHP 5.3+. Below that version you can replace `__DIR__` by `dirname(__FILE__)`

BTW, [**autoloading**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) is a good practice to avoid includes mess.

Comment: It be usefull even "dirname(__FILE__)"

Comment: I have the following result: `Warning: require_once(G:\wamp\www\testincludes/core.inc.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in G:\wamp\www\test\index.php on line 13`  Back slash and forward slashes ...

Comment: Forward/backward slashes mix should not be a problem for PHP on Windows (quoting the manual: `On Windows, both slash (/) and backslash (\) are used as directory separator character. In other environments, it is the forward slash (/).`). The problem is not on file `core.inc.php` but on file `index.php` which seem to not exist in `G:\wamp\www\test`. Please read carefully the error messages you get.

Comment: Let me try again and I will publish the answer right away...

Comment: Cheers! Thank you Frosty. Now it worked. Your this comment `Forward/backward slashes mix should not be a problem for PHP on Windows` really helped me. Otherwise \ and / confused me and stopped me to try again. Thank you one more time.

Answer (score 1):

included file in `index.php` : `include_once ('./includes/core.inc.php');`

Answer (score 0):

Your relative path in index.php pointing to the core.inc.php is simply wrong.

You are saying: "From the location of index.php, on directory up, and there it is." But there is no file "core.inc.php" in the "www" directory.

The correct path is "includes/core.inc.php": From the current directory "www/test" one directory up into "includes" and there it is.

Any mentions of using `__DIR__` or `__FILE__` magic constants will also work, but this is a different approach: It will create an absolute path to the file by using relative additions. It works the same, but looks more complicated.

If you are using classes, try to implement autoloading. Then you do not need to include files explicitly, you simply use the classes.

Comment: Can you hint me what classes I should use. __FILE__ actually shows directory where the file is located with backslashes like `G:\wamp\www\test\includes\core.inc.php`. However include function needs forward slashed paths like  `/includes/core.inc.php`. When you append both I think it will currupt.

Comment: Sorry the path is typing mistake. Of course I have checked the included path was exactly as you said. `include_once ('indcludes/core.inc.php');` check I have corrected

Comment: PHP does not care about slashes being forward or backward - it automatically converts them to the ones that are needed on the platform it runs on. `include` only needs the path (relative or absolute) and filename. You can even mix them when concatenating the string from `__DIR__` and the last part. The only thing to be sure: Do not omit a slash! The result from `__DIR__` does not end with a slash.